# Localhost is not working but localhost:8080 is working

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Ez9.png)I used Xampp to turn on the Apache Server with ports 4433 and 8080.
http://localhost is not working while http://localhost:8080 is redirecting to the Xampp dashboard.

Comment: You can only assign one port to run this server and in this case it is 8080.

Comment: localhost without port is by definition 80 and as you moved 80 to 8080 you have to attach it

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm seeing two ports over here.